# Unable to award bounty

Tags: bug, bounty

A bounty I had [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56437551/208880) expired, but when I went to award the bounty the little award boxes are not showing up.

Anyone know why, and how can I get the bounty awarded?

Comment: The award boxes are not showing up because the grace period expired. You read your email late unfortunately. If you see the timestamps on the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56437551/timeline) you had a week + the grace period before the bounty was removed.

Comment: @SamuelLiew:  Three days ago I got a "Your bounty expires in three days"; yesterday I got a "Your bounty expires in one day"; I do not see a "Your bounty is in the grace period" anywhere.

Comment: @EthanFurman In your on-site notifications, you get one at 3 days left, one at 1 day left, and one at grace period end. The message that your grace period started is sent via *email*, and that is recorded as having been sent out.